# How do i get the result from provided URL without opening the browser [Php Code/AJAX]

Tags: java, php, javascript, ajax

How do i get the result from provided URL without opening the browser using php programming/AJAX.

### This is the url provided by SMS gateway

```
http://isms.mobiweb.com.my/isms_send.php?un=username&pwd=password&dstno=60168126323&msg=Hi%20Chin...%20Tested%20by%20joe.&type=1&sendid=60132729040
```

Basically I am using cron-job scrip to start processing and send SMS to the recipients.
What I want is just the result from the URL(Without opening the browser for gateway api) and proceed the to next process.

### The api result will be

```
-1000   UNKNOWN ERROR
-1001   AUTHENTICATION FAILED
-1002   ACCOUNT SUSPENDED / EXPIRED
-1003   IP NOT ALLOWED
-1004   INSUFFICIENT CREDITS
-1005   INVALID SMS TYPE
-1006   INVALID BODY LENGTH (1-900)
-1007   INVALID HEX BODY
-1008   MISSING PARAMETER
-2000   SUCCESS
```

Thank you

Comment: If it's just PHP you want, is there a specific reason you've tagged the question with Java, Javascript and ASP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to fetch the url.

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents('http://isms.mobiweb.com.my/isms_send.php?un=username&pwd=password&dstno=60168126323&msg=Hi%20Chin...%20Tested%20by%20joe.&type=1&sendid=60132729040');
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Wow... this is great... Very simple... Thanks you sir!